# iOS - adding a sandbox tester generates an error: "There are one or more validation errors below"

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, sandbox, apple-id

While trying adding a sandbox tester we get this error: "There are one or more validation errors below" ,yet we cant see any error:
[image]

In the dev tool: we can see the nature of the error: "The email is already used"
[image]

The only problem is that the email is not in the testers list and not being used.
Any ideas ?

Comment: I am facing same error, Any solution for it?

Comment: @SantoshSingh so from what i understood the sandbox is for in app purchase so if you are not using that you dont need the sandbox.

Comment: Yes, I am creating Sandbox user in app purchase testing.

Comment: @SantoshSingh you can make it the answer :)